# Why could a call to `getaddrinfo()` fail with `EAI_SYSTEM` and errno set to `EBUSY` ("Device or resource busy")?

Tags: linux, lxc, system-calls, glibc, container

I'm seeing this error when running `apt update` in containers, if that is useful information. apt spits out:

```
System error resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:80' - getaddrinfo (16: Device or resource busy)
```

I tried looking at the glibc source but I could not understand what was going on.

- [[glibc.git] / resolv / getaddrinfo_a.c](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=resolv/getaddrinfo_a.c;h=60e31405538fccd6a82f43b81778140ca2a28654;hb=HEAD#l36)

Comment: This sounds like your reason - https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26510.

Comment: And this - https://docs.docker.com/storage/troubleshooting_volume_errors/

Comment: Can you elaborate on the container scenario you're dealing w/? Are you doing any bind mounting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542783/sharing-files-between-two-containers

Comment: I am running `apt update` in a LXC privileged ubuntu bionic container. Pretty typical bridged networking setup. I'm not sure what that stackoverflow question has to do with this. This is a name resolution error.

Comment: You didn't give much to go on, so I'm throwing leads back to you.

Comment: You can use `strace` to see if there is a relevant system call failing with EBUSY (or a different failure e.g. which matches what JdeBP describes)

Answer (score 2):

Your container is not fully functional, and the GNU C library's Name Service Switch functions do not work in it.  Specifically, they cannot dynamically load `_nss_N_gethostbyname3_r`/`_nss_N_gethostbyname2_r`.  `getaddrinfo()` returns with `errno` set to `EBUSY` (and `h_errno` set to `NETDB_INTERNAL`) in such circumstances.

You are also looking at the source code of the wrong function.  That is `getaddrinfo_a()`.

Comment: How can I handle the dynamic loading issue to make my container functional again?

Answer (score 2):

Check your access rights. In my case /etc/hosts was mode 0600 which works for root but apt drops privileges when downloading.

Other fun places to check:

- /lib, /lib/ARCH_TRIPLE, /lib/ARCH_TRIPLE/libnss_dns.so
- /etc/resolv.conf
- /usr, /usr/bin

Comment: thanks matthias; this container is long gone but maybe that will help in the future